My tool is missing
My Move, Rotate, Scale, etc.. All my tool cursors are missing.  I click on the tool on the side bar and I'm still working with only the vertex.  Shouldn't I see the move tool?
What's going on?


hello could you please show the whole interface?

Hello and welcome. Please don't crop out essential information from your screenshots, this hides away any details that could possibly hint at what your issue is. As it stands a partial screenshot of the subject without context or further information makes it impossible to diagnose the issue. Please edit your post and replace your images with full uncropped screenshots showing the user interface, properties, and any relevant parameters that might help us solve the issue.

I feel what you are missing is probably the gizmo, not the tool, right? Could you edit your post and clarify these points in the body and title of your post?

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I would translate "tool cursors" to "gizmos" so yes, he's missing the gizmo.

Hello All,
Sorry force of habit, I don't like including entire screen shots.  I've updated my screen shot and included the menu.

As @moonboots said, when you are asking questions like this it could be helpful to show the whole interface because we might see things you are not aware of. Since you do not show the complete menu bar, I can only guess that you have disabled the Viewport Gizmos:


YES!! THANKS FIXED IT!! THANK YOU!!!
Why is this a little button?  Shouldn't it be in the Menu?  It's so hard to notice if this is not turned on.

@JimmyLin Well, it is usually turned on by default when you install Blender...
